# Pre-select the dropdown select option according to value received

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, select

I have a table of bookings in which the last field is of status with dropdown as

```
<td><select id="selectID" ng-selected="{{data.status}}">
                               <option value="1">New</option>
                               <option value="2">To Be Approved</option>
                               <option value="3">Cancelled</option>
                               <option value="4">Rejected</option>
                               <option value="5">Approved</option>
                               <option value="6">On The Way</option>
                               <option value="7">Delivered</option>
                               <option value="8">Ongoing</option>
                               <option value="9">Checkedout</option>
                               <option value="10">Completed</option>
                               <option value="11">Invoice Pending</option>
                               <option value="12">Invoice Sent/Payment Pending</option>
                               <option value="13">Green</option>

                           </select> </td>
```

I receive the value of status in the JSON as a number between 1-12. I want to pre-select every drop-down  when i load my table . eg If JSON has status as 2 , then default selected in the row with status must be "To be approved" and so on . I have looked a lot , but all i could find was ng-options which is used to populate the select tag , but i don't receive them in the JSON so i have hard coded it in the `<td>` tags where each row is working on `ng-repeat`. Also , I  thought of using `.val` function but i guess for different rows i might have to set different ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use AngularJS data binding with `ng-model`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/3gkwx9ra/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">{{data.status}}
    <td>
        <select id="selectID" ng-model="data.status">
            <option value="1">New</option>
            <option value="2">To Be Approved</option>
            <option value="3">Cancelled</option>
            <option value="4">Rejected</option>
            <option value="5">Approved</option>
            <option value="6">On The Way</option>
            <option value="7">Delivered</option>
            <option value="8">Ongoing</option>
            <option value="9">Checkedout</option>
            <option value="10">Completed</option>
            <option value="11">Invoice Pending</option>
            <option value="12">Invoice Sent/Payment Pending</option>
            <option value="13">Green</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = {
        status: 2
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-selected` works on `option` tag and not on `select` tag.

See this snippet:

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.selectedItem = 3;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <section ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <select>
      <option ng-selected="selectedItem == 1" value="1">1</option>
      <option ng-selected="selectedItem == 2" value="2">2</option>
      <option ng-selected="selectedItem == 3" value="3">3</option>
      <option ng-selected="selectedItem == 4" value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: i know about ng-selected , but i still wrote it there to ask whether it can be done throough this or not , anyways got my answer , thnx anyways.